# ActionScript USB microphone stutter

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, audio-recording, microphone

I have a problem with USB mic input. When using my laptops internal microphone the following recorded buffer plays back just fine:

```
microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();
microphone.codec = SoundCodec.SPEEX;
microphone.setLoopBack(false);
microphone.rate = 16;
microphone.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, processMicData);

private function gotMicData(micData:SampleDataEvent):void {
   micBuffer.writeBytes(micData.data);
}
```

But when I select the USB mic the sound stutters, like it's adding silence between the buffers. By the way, if I use a program like Audacity to record the USB microphone, everything works fine.

Comment: It's common thing, audio latency, which varies by the system, You might have default settings 48 khz on USB device and Flash tries to convert it to 44.1 khz, or Audacity goes through some kind of ASIO driver to minimize latency. You can read goo article about realtime audio in the Flash, might help: http://philippseifried.com/blog/2011/10/07/dynamic-audio-in-as3-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend trying to use the Microphone.setSilenceLevel() method. It allows you to set a level of microphone activity necessary for flash to read the audio input. Then, when no input is recorded, it won't write in silence when no information is received.

For more info:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d0c.html